# How to sort a date in table using mat-sort? . The date format should in dd-MM-yyyy format

Tags: angular, typescript

When using mat-sort for dd-MM-yyyy format. I am facing an issue like the order is mismatching and I think this is sorting based on date(dd), as I mentioned in the below image

[My response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsGAF.png)

this is my code,

Html:

```
                        <table class="interviewed-status-table" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
                            <thead style="background-color: #f6f9fc;">
                                <tr>
                                    <th mat-sort-header="fromDate" class="table-head text-center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FROM&nbsp;DATE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>                                                                                                                       
                                    <th mat-sort-header="toDate" class="table-head text-center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TO&nbsp;DATE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                                    <th mat-sort-header="subTotal" class="table-head text-center">SUBTOTAL</th>
                                    <th mat-sort-header="cashAdvance" class="table-head text-center">ADVANCE</th>
                                    <th mat-sort-header="finalbalance" class="table-head text-center">BALANCE ADVANCE</th>
                                    <th mat-sort-header="totalReimbursement" class="table-head text-center">TOTAL REIMBURSEMENT</th>
                                    <th class="table-head text-center">VIEW APPROVERS</th>
                                    <th class="table-head text-center">APPROVAL&nbsp;&nbsp;STATUS</th>
                                    <!-- <th class="table-head text-center">STATUS</th>-->
                                    <th class="table-head text-center">ACTION</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let expenseReimbursement of expenseReimbursementListFiltered | searchFilter: query | paginate: { itemsPerPage: mySelect, currentPage: p } ">
                                    <td class="table-data text-center">{{expenseReimbursement.fromDate}}</td>
                                    <td class="table-data text-center">{{expenseReimbursement.toDate}}</td> 
                                    <td class="table-data text-center">{{expenseReimbursement.subTotal}}</td>
                                    <td class="table-data text-center">{{expenseReimbursement.cashAdvance}}</td> 
                                    <td *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.totalReimbursement == 0" class="table-data text-center">{{expenseReimbursement.finalbalance}}</td> 
                                    <td *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.totalReimbursement  > 0" class="table-data text-center">0.00</td> 
                                    <td class="table-data text-center">{{expenseReimbursement.totalReimbursement}}</td>
                                    <td class="table-data text-center">
                                        <mat-icon class="view-icon" *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.approval != undefined" 
                                        (click)="viewapproverstatus(expenseReimbursement)">visibility</mat-icon>
                                        <span *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.approval == undefined">  --  </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- <td class="table-data" >{{expenseReimbursement.approver.employeeName}}</td>  -->
                                    <!-- <td class="table-data text-center text-success" *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.approval == undefined">Saved as Draft</td> -->

                                    <td class="table-data text-center">
                                        <div *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.approval != undefined">
                                            <span class="text-success" *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.approval.approvalStatus.listTypeValueName == 'Approved'">
                                                {{expenseReimbursement.approval.approvalStatus.listTypeValueName}}
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="text-warning" *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.approval.approvalStatus.listTypeValueName == 'Pending'">
                                                {{expenseReimbursement.approval.approvalStatus.listTypeValueName}}
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.approval.approvalStatus.listTypeValueName == 'Denied'">
                                                {{expenseReimbursement.approval.approvalStatus.listTypeValueName}}
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="text-success" *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.approval == undefined">Saved as Draft</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- <td *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.status.listTypeValueName =='Active'" class="table-data text-center text-success">
                                        <ul id="nav">
                                            <li class="text-center dropdown-list" style=" border: 1px solid green;">
                                                <a class="text-success dropdown-list-status" *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.status.listTypeValueName =='Active'">{{expenseReimbursement.status.listTypeValueName}}</a>
                                                <span>
                                                    <mat-icon class="dropdown-list-icon text-success" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example arrow_drop_down">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
                                                </span>
                                                <ul  class="dropdown-item" (click)="statuschangeactive(expenseReimbursement.status)">
                                                    <li class="material-menu">
                                                        <a class="text-danger dropdown-item-status-inactive">In-Active</a>
                                                        <mat-icon class="text-danger material-menu-icon" aria-hidden="false">do_disturb</mat-icon>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                    <td *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.status.listTypeValueName =='In-Active'" class=" table-data text-center text-danger">
                                        <ul id="nav">
                                            <li class="text-center dropdown-list" style=" border: 1px solid red;">
                                                <a class="text-danger dropdown-list-status" *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.status.listTypeValueName =='In-Active'">{{expenseReimbursement.status.listTypeValueName}}</a>
                                                <span>
                                                    <mat-icon class="dropdown-list-icon text-danger" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example arrow_drop_down">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
                                                </span>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-item" (click)="statuschangeinactive(expenseReimbursement.status)">
                                                    <li class="material-menu">
                                                        <a class="text-success dropdown-item-status-active">Active</a>
                                                        <mat-icon class="material-menu-icon text-success" aria-hidden="false">verified</mat-icon>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>-->
                                    <td class="table-data text-center">
                                        <button class="menu-button"
                                            mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
                                            <mat-icon class="menu-icon">more_vert</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                                            <button mat-menu-item (click)="openDialog(expenseReimbursement.expenseReimbursementId)">
                                                <mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined viewicon">visibility</mat-icon>
                                                <span mat-button class="text">View</span>
                                            </button>
                                            <!-- <button *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.approval != undefined" mat-menu-item>
                                                <div *ngIf="expenseReimbursement.draft == true" 
                                                (click)="updateexpensereburisment(expenseReimbursement.expenseReimbursementId)">
                                                    <mat-icon class="material-icons-round edit-icon">edit</mat-icon>
                                                    <span class="text">Edit</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </button> -->
                                            <button [disabled]="expenseReimbursement.approval" mat-menu-item>
                                                <div (click)="updateexpensereburisment(expenseReimbursement.expenseReimbursementId)">
                                                    <mat-icon class="material-icons-round edit-icon">edit</mat-icon>
                                                    <span class="text">Edit</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </button>
                                        </mat-menu>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Ts:

Note: I used here compare method.

```
  sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.expenseReimbursementListFiltered.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      this.expenseReimbursementListFiltered = data;
      return;
    }

    this.expenseReimbursementListFiltered = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (sort.active) {
        case 'fromDate':
          return this.compare(a.fromDate, b.fromDate, isAsc);
        case 'toDate':
          return this.compare(a.toDate, b.toDate, isAsc);
        case 'subTotal':
          return this.compare(a.subTotal, b.subTotal, isAsc);
        case 'cashAdvance':
          return this.compare(a.cashAdvance, b.cashAdvance, isAsc);
        case 'finalbalance':
          return this.compare(a.finalbalance, b.finalbalance, isAsc);
        case 'totalReimbursement':
          return this.compare(a.totalReimbursement, b.totalReimbursement, isAsc);
        default:
          return 0;
      }
    });
  }
  compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) {
    return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
  }
```

I want proper sorting for dates in the table in dd/MM/yyyy format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is add a new property "formateddDate" to the elements of your array

```
expenseReimbursement .forEach((x:any)=>{
   x.fromDateFormatted=x.fromDate.split('-').reverse().join();
   x.ToDateFormatted=x.toDate.split('-').reverse().join();
})
```

And use this "properties" when sort, see that they are string in the way "yyyyMMdd"

NOTE: use new Date("dd-MM-yyyy") it's not correct, to create a new Date from string the string should be in "standard format" `yyyy-MM-dd`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert this date object with new date()

```
    case 'fromDate':
      return this.compare(new Date(a.fromDate), new Date(b.fromDate), isAsc);
    case 'toDate':
      return this.compare(new Date(a.toDate), new Date(b.toDate), isAsc);
```

Because , it considers the date value in string format.
Hope this will work , because I have used this way

Comment: Use new Date("dd-MM-yyyy") it's not correct, to create a new Date from string the string should be in "standard format" yyyy-MM-dd, e.g. `new Date('20-12-2020')` for 20th of December, give you Invalid Date

Comment: Thank you GouriSankar, Your code is working perfectly, but I asked for the 26-09-2022 (dd/MM/yyyy) format, for this format it is not sorting perfectly. Thank you.